# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jmespath'

Tags: python, opencv, jmespath

I am trying to download a flower dataset from Open Images Dataset, using OIDv4(https://github.com/EscVM/OIDv4_ToolKit)  The program can run, but the end result is a huge CSV file comprising of the entire Open Images Dataset and zero images

I am running the program on an anaconda virtual environment, and the required libraries have already been installed. The following is the error messaage I am getting

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\aws.cmd", line 50, in <module>
File association not found for extension .py
import awscli.clidriver
File "C:\Users\xlim027\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
import botocore.session
File "C:\Users\xlim027\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 31, in <module>
import botocore.client
 File "C:\Users\xlim027\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 16, in <module>
 from botocore import waiter, xform_name
 File "C:\Users\xlim027\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 13, in <module>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 import jmespath
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jmespath'
```

Comment: Have you tried to install that package manually ?

Comment: I completely removed my python env and it works

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the package manually:

```
pip3 install jmespath
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7qhp7y/importerror_no_module_named_jmespath/

Answer (score 2):

When pip3 was not installed (yet) - this helped me

```
sudo apt-get install python3-jmespath
```